# Stream video from HDMI in to NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, video, video-streaming

What I am trying to accomplish is to take a video stream in through HDMI port on my macbook pro and display the video inside a NSView or window.

My end goal is to do something like this:

```
dvd player -- HDMI in --> computer -> apply overlay to video -- HDMI out --> tv
```

I am not sure if I will be able to stream the video out the other side so if I can simply get it to:

```
dvd player -- HDMI in --> computer -> apply overlay to video --> display in NSView or window
```

I will be satisfied. I have download the apple example code for applying an overlay to a quicktime video which is trivial, it is the input streaming part I am lost on. I'm guessing a way to say it would be that I need my computer act as a "pass through device"? for video. Not sure if this is a correct way to say that I'm trying to do. Any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AVFoundation which works exactly like it does on iOS.

Apple documentation will walk you through connecting AVCaptureDevice to the AVCaptureOutput (your AVPlayer hooked up to a UI).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for just couldn't seem to find it. Thank you very much for the help +1

Comment: @Fruity_Geek have you managed to get this apple sample to work? I followed everything to the T but it won't play. Everything loads fine but no video :(

Comment: Try downloading one of their sample projects like AVSimpleEditorOSX to see it in action. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVSimpleEditorOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012253

Comment: @Fruity_Geek I was able to get it to work. By subclassing NSView as in their example it would never work. Turns out my whole idea isn't going to work :-/